# Need information on windows scripting and supporting scripting in my C# application

Tags: c#, windows-scripting

I'm trying wrap my head around all of the different scripting technologies for Windows (what are they, and which are the most common) and ultimately to figure out what type of scripting to add to my application.

I've read that with .NET 4 it's easy to make your program scriptable via dynamic languages like IronRuby and IronPython (or even VB or C# which might be more confusing for a user?) My understanding is that pre .NET 4 the way to add scripting support for your application was to make it a COM/OLE object so people could use vbscript, winbatch, shell scripts, or another scripting language (or really any language that supported COM) to control your application? What are the common scripting languages use? I've heard a lot of people talk about VB for Applications. Is that a dynamic language or a compiled language and to allow my application to be scriptable via VB for Applications would I have to support COM/OLE? I think I'm leaning towards supporting IronRuby and IronPython since it seems simple to implement support for them, but can those languages also be used to script Windows or other applications in general (and thus scripts for your application could have more features than what you laid out)? How would you go about designing your application to be scriptable?

I know that seems like a thousands questions, but really what I'm looking for is just an explanation of the scripting technologies for windows (what are the main differences, how frequently are they used) and which ones are the most common/standard to support when making your application scriptable?

Thanks in advance everyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to create dynamic objects in your apppool or view the values of something in your memory.  If you need access to you objects then I would say maybe you could put a scripting window in your program.  If you are just trying to configure certain aspects of you program you and look at adding modules to windows powershell for your admins.  That seems to be what microsoft is doing for things like sharepoint and sql server.  I would look up if powershell can fit your needs so that users can use the language they are confortable with and write there own scripts but if not then take a look at adding one of the dynamic languages to your app.  If slashdot is to be believed today then Microsoft is not going to be persuing them as agressively.

Comment: +1, that heads up on the future of DLR helped in considering what to use! I'd like to have scripts available for custom commands (like if someone pressed 'button1' on the gui it would run a user's script associated with button1) that could interact with objects in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling Game Development Kit 2 will actually compile code entered in the UI rather than interpret it as script.  (It uses the C# compiler provided with the framework.)  It can then run and reflect on that code at runtime.  Have you considered a solution like that?

Comment: yeah, I've seen an example online that does something like -assuming you mean C# code compiled at run time? I think C# or VB would be over kill. I'd basically just like a few objects (like the display) accessible to scripting and I'd like the script's code to be in language a power user but who is not necessarily a programmer might know.